# Disallow words less than 3 characters

Tags: ios, swift, uitextchecker

In the Swift code below, the user chooses a word and types it into a text box, 
now how to disallow the words entered if less than 3 characters in length?

```
func isReal (word: String) -> Bool {
    //return true
    let checker = UITextChecker()
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, word.utf16.count)
    let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")
    return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound
}
```

Comment: Is the input coming from a `UITextField`? `UITextChecker` was designed to check spelling issues, not arbitrary input constraints, so you shouldn't use that.

Comment: sorry i'm not getting you ... ! the input is by the user in the textField yes ...
this is what i want to do here ---> Disallow answers that are shorter than three letters. The easiest way to accomplish this is to put a check into isReal() that returns false if the word length is under three letters, the question is ..... How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add an `if` to check if the word has more than 3 characters:

```
func isReal (word: String) -> Bool {
    if word.characters.count >= 3 {
        //return true
        let checker = UITextChecker()
        let range = NSMakeRange(0, word.utf16.count)
        let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")
        return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

This way, if `word` is shorter than 3 characters, it will return `false`, otherwise, it will test against the `UITextChecker()` and then return `true` or `false` respectively

EDIT: Alternative using `guard`:

```
func isReal (word: String) -> Bool {
    guard word.characters.count >= 3 else {
        return false
    }

    //return true
    let checker = UITextChecker()
    let range = NSMakeRange(0, word.utf16.count)
    let misspelledRange = checker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: word, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en")
    return misspelledRange.location == NSNotFound
}
```

If the `guard` statement is not met (being word.characters.count < 3), the function will automatically return `false`

Comment: The `else` statement is not necessary but it's clearer this way

Comment: actually i want to limit the answers to be minimum of 3 characters not less than that ....

Comment: @DantePuglisi, `guard` instead of `if/else` would be even clearer.

Comment: @user28434 totally, will add it as an alternative

Comment: how to use guard ?

Comment: @AmirFendi I added it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the didEndEditing UItextfieldDelegate method and then check 1) that its a single word and 2) that its longer than 2 characters.  At that point you then need to show an error or a red caption label or something.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextFieldDidEndEditingReason) {
    guard let string = textField.text else {
        return
    }
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    if characterSet.intersection(CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty != true {
        // we have white space!
    }
    if string.characters.count < 3 {
        // too short
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement new functions to check an input coming from a `UITextField`. `UITextField` has its own functions for that. You should make your ViewController class conform to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol, set it as the delegate for your `UITextField`, then implement the required delegate method, `textFieldDidEndEditing` and check the length of the input there.

```
extension YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let input = textField.text else {return}
        if input.characters.count < 3 {
            //handle error
        }
    }
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` of `YourViewController`:

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```